# How do I publish an update to Dashclock when my application receives an Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dashclock

I have added a location proximity later using Android's `addProximityAlert` method in the `LocationManager` class.

When the user's phone is a particular area, the `LocationManager` sends an `Intent` to my application's `BroadcastReciver` and here is the class that handles the intent:

```
public class ProximityTrigger extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context ctxContext, Intent ittIntent) {            
        System.out.println(ittIntent.getIntExtra(WidgetService.KEY_STOP_IDENTIFIER, -1));               
    }

}
```

I'd like to use the DashClock API to show an update when this happens. DashClock has a [`publishUpdate`](http://api.dashclock.googlecode.com/git/reference/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/api/DashClockExtension.html#publishUpdate%28com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.ExtensionData%29) method that can be used to show updates but I can only use this from my extension class that extends the [`DashClock`](http://api.dashclock.googlecode.com/git/reference/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/api/DashClockExtension.html) class. This should be a possible somehow but I can't seem to figure out how. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the extension service must issue the [publishUpdate](http://api.dashclock.googlecode.com/git/reference/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/api/DashClockExtension.html#publishUpdate(com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.ExtensionData)) call, your proximity trigger broadcast receiver should use something like a **broadcast or an event bus** to ask the extension to publish an update.

If the extension isn't initialized, meaning the user hasn't added it or DashClock isn't running, then nothing will happen, which is the expected and correct behavior. As soon as DashClock starts and your extension is added, [onUpdateData](http://api.dashclock.googlecode.com/git/reference/com/google/android/apps/dashclock/api/DashClockExtension.html#onUpdateData(int)) will be called and you'll be able to publish your update.

For some ideas on the actual classes you can use, see below:

- **Global broadcasts**, using [Context.sendBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) along with a dynamically registered broadcast receiver in your `DashClockExtension` using [Context.registerReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)).
- **Local broadcasts**, using [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).
- **[Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/) or [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)**, two frameworks that let application components publish and subscribe to events. In this case, the extension subscribes and your proximity sensor publishes.

A full code snippet for global broadcasts can be found in [issue 292](https://code.google.com/p/dashclock/issues/detail?id=292) on the DashClock project page.

Comment: I'd give you several upvotes if I could. You've been a great help Roman!

Comment: I added a code snippet to the aforementioned issue 292 for local broadcasts too.

Comment: @KentonPrice, could you explain the difference between the local-broadcasts and the global-broadcasts. Which one should I use? I haven't found any results on Google which explain the differences between the two. Thank you.

Comment: Local broadcasts means only your app sees it. Global broadcasts can by default be seen by all apps.